# Could I please request an introduction to philosophy of pessimism?

Tags: nietzsche, existentialism, meaning-of-life, schopenhauer, camus

Everything from essential texts, interpretations of the absurd, eternal return, interpretations of suicide and religion, and it's influence on the arts. And, I know I am asking a lot, but I'd like to know if it has helped you find meaning? I very much venture into existentially nihilistic approaches to meaning (although I hate this), and believe the most inspirational, life-affirming and hopeful way to cope with this is to create your own meaning (whether or not that still qualifies as nihilism, I'm unsure). I'd very much appreciate an answer on this. I find that the whole philosophy of pessimism to be extremely (using this word again) hopeful. Although I'm in my mid-twenties, I've struggled with existential despair for a long time, so I'm particularly interested in this (am I just a little oddball for finding affirmation in what is seen as such a bleak, cold subject...?). Thank you all very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Phil SE. That's a lot in one question indeed! Did you see [Wikipedia's Philosophical pessimism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessimism#Philosophical_pessimism)? They recommend [Dienstag's Pessimism: Philosophy, Ethic, Spirit](https://books.google.com/books/about/Pessimism.html?id=zdxYIdhod3wC) for introduction. Also, the founding father, Schopenhauer, wrote oddly uplifting [Essays and Aphorisms](https://books.google.com/books?id=EWt_5YLqHcAC), which are far more life-wise and accessible than The World as Will and Representation.